# jQuery: how to trigger only current menu and remove style attribute if its value display : none?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATED**

I have tried this,

```
$('.menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a').after('<span class="arrow"> </span>');
$('.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children > a').after('<span class="arrow"> </span>');

$('span.arrow').click(function(){
    var active = $(this).closest('li').find('.sub-menu');
    active.slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

how can I remove style attribute that has `display:none` when menu toggles to slideUp.

and 2nd problem is that when I toggle first menu all other its child menus toggles too, means toggling first menu also toggles its child menus too.
I don't want it.

the only current menu should toggles or slides, all should not.

here is [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hsn0/r42fg8uk/3/)

so how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('span.arrow').click(function(){
    var active = $(this).closest('li.menu-item-has-children').children("ul");
    active.slideToggle()

});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r42fg8uk/5/)

Comment: thanks bro :)

its awesome. very happy you did this.

Comment: but there is 1 problem left, it is for responsive desgn.

when I restore my browser to larger than mobile device the sub-menus doesn't hovered :(

Comment: that's why I also asking how to remove style attr if `display:none`

Comment: What do you mean "larger than mobile"?

Comment: I am using @media queries, this menu is only for mobile devices, I mean when I resize my browser larger than 800px the menu that is for not mobile devices doesn't hover.

Comment: I'm using lot larger than 800px and works fine :) Can you create a fiddle to demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60198/discussion-between-alek-and-hsn0331).

Comment: when you toggle again menu its attribute sets to `display:none` and it stills there in inline state, so when you resize your browser to greater than 800px you cant hover its sub-menus.

Comment: Can you join chat room please?